# Germanium vs. silicon

Tags: relay

I am using a 12 volt relay to operate an AC electric water valve (120 volts.)

The problem is that the circuit worked well at first. I placed 2 germanium diodes across the relay terminals to protect the 2N3904 transistor which drives the relay in response to a pulse from a 555 timer.

The timer pulse is basically controlled by liquid level at 3 points: pins 8, 2, 6. I am using a jar for testing the operation. I'm thinking that the diodes are not enough to do the job and back EMF breaking past is destroying the transistor, the diodes, and eventually the chip as well. The circuit diagram calls for a 1N4007 diode which I don't have and used the 2 mentioned as a replacement causing me to think on those terms.

Can anyone explain this to me?

This is the edit asked for:

The three probes signal the valve circuit. When water is present, pins 2 and 8 probes read bottom level and pin 6 probe reads upper level and signals AC shut off. The valve will operate when needed but the circuit will not stop the AC when the water level reaches pin 6 probe. Pins 6 and 2 are also connected to ground by 390k resistors each. (Values of which have also been changed a few times.)

The relay I used was a typical one that could have been had from poor defunct Radio Shack. When I hooked this up, I used an LED to monitor the action of the relay contacts. Had it been stuck in a position I would have known about it. Besides, when the relay activates, it will turn on the AC going to the valve and an AC monitoring light.

The output level from pin 3 is also monitored. I now have the correct diode called for in the schematic installed and have put back the resistors called for.

What went wrong is this:

After a few tests with the jar and water, the operation began to fail for some reason.The probes made from #12 solid copper wire (tinted) and connected to the pins on the chip as mentioned by a run of #22 or 24 copper wire about 4'long (like residential phone cable.)

Some impurities in the water may have caused the probes to discolor prior to the sanding and tinting interfering with the signal from them. It still did not work after. I have changed the key components several times now and tested them on another PCB. Some components failed testing, others did not. Working components are now installed. So,this is where I stand now. My thinking is that the probes are causing the problem somehow. I want to upload the schematic but have not found out how to do it.

Comment: Please draw a schematic of your circuit and provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the Ge diodes.

Comment: Link to relay datasheet too please.

Comment: Germanium?! Where do people dig such nightmares up? Germanium diodes are completely obsolete for switching purposes; since nearly 50 years!! Use a Schottky diode instead. And throw out the source that recommended Germanium.

Comment: there is no shortage of suitable diodes from modern e-waste like PC power supplies or power supplies in just about anything - TV, DVD players, laptop bricks etc. There's plenty of useful components you can harvest for nix.

Comment: @MarcusMüller LOL- They do have low forward drop, but they're so leaky that they're barely diodes at all :)  I wouldn't even know where to find one these days so the OP probably found some NOS diodes somewhere.

Comment: @JohnD there's old supply that is still being sold 1. to military with legacy devices in need of maintenance/replacement, 2. to people who read 60 year old schematics and think people back then were cleverer, so, radio amateurs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well... my very first radio project as a kid was a crystal radio receiver using a crystal of galena (from south america) mounted in molten lead that was left to cool around it. Galena has a band gap of about 0.4 eV. A 1N34A germanium diode is considered (by some anyway) to be an okay replacement. Germanium at room temp has a band gap of about 0.66 eV, I think. Si, of course, is much higher at about 1.1 eV. May need to add another group to your list?

Comment: @jonk you'll appreciate how much I think of "build your own junction" as an *awesome* approach to building your own receiver, but "my schematic is a copy of a copy of a bad scan of a magazine from the 1970s who copied it from a book, ripped of some other website, and consequentially contains Ge diodes" to be *not awesome*.

Comment: (thing here is: you built that, appreciating the process, and building something that was good in the sense that it satisfied a curiosity *and* was a technically feasible solution. Catching the flyback from a relay with Ge diodes in 2022 doesn't tick the same boxes, at least for me)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your list was fine. I just wanted to add another entry to your table. :) And obviously I agree with you about using germanium in this application. I was just being pedantic. I think Kartman has the right of it -- any failed compact fluorescent lightbulb, for example, will have the necessary diode(s) inside. Just open it up and they are there. So, if the OP doesn't have a 1N4007 on hand, the OP can scavenge one up. Like I used to do. (I still do, actually -- laser printers are where I get optics for measuring the speed of light in water vs air, for example.)

Comment: laser interferometry, I presume, @jonk?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No. The rotating octagonal mirror is used more as shown [here](https://opik.fyysika.ee/index.php/book/section/8646). Very easy to set up! I have a Melles Griot 10 mW HeNe laser that I use.

Comment: oh, an experimental classic!

Comment: @MarcusMüller What I dislike is that the cheaper laser printers are now using squares instead of those wonderful octagonals. Plus they are SMALLER making my setup slightly more difficult. I think there should be a LAW requiring those beautiful octagonals and of a certain width and diameter, too. So that I would always have a nice supply of good quality optics. ;) But the laser printers also have my nice "flats" -- mirrors that I need. So I can't complain too much.

Comment: You write that "the circuit worked well at first", but you didn't tell us exactly what has gone wrong. For example, it could be that the relay is stuck on (or off), or that there is no longer a signal going to the relay coil. Please [edit] the question to add that information so that we don't have to guess what went wrong.

Comment: I just compared OA150 and 1N4007 connected to a typical automotive 12 V relay (72 mH, 70 ohm) for some hundred cycles @10 Hz. The current decay of the germanium diode was around 5ms because it has much higher resistance, the silicon diode needed 10ms. So switching speed is better with the germanium diode.

Comment: Make a picture of your circuit diagram (screenshot or export from your design program.) Edit your question, then click the icon that looks like two mountains (two white triangles on a gray background.)  Pick your saved schematic picture and insert it.

Answer (score 2):

1N4007 is a 1A silicon switching diode specified with 1000V breakdown voltage (plain silly for a snubber diode for a 12V relay).  Germanium diodes have much lower reverse voltage ratings, like 10V for an 1N34A.  That is presumably why you put two in series in order to make up for the 12V of reverse voltage they'll be subjected to.  However, their voltage-dependent reverse current is not dependable enough to split the 12V into approximately equal parts: more likely than not one diode will get most of the reverse voltage and will get destroyed first, taking the other along.

Germanium is plain silly in this application: you could probably use any silicon diode (that has sufficient reverse voltage tolerance, ruling out a Zener or a transistor's B-E diode) instead.

Comment: What makes you believe that the Ge diodes are **in series**?

Comment: ...and, a 12V coil is likely to give back spikes of well over 20V.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Abysmally low voltage rating. They often came in stacks to give useful voltage rating.

Comment: @winny Are we certain that the OP understands that? I think it's equally likely that they put the Ge diodes in parallel to try to achieve a current rating similar to a single 1N4007.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Far from it. My bet is that OP is confusing Ge with Schottky.

Answer (score 2):

The germanium diodes are fragile. It's easy to damage them just by getting them too hot during soldering. And they are not rated for the application.

Instead, use any silicon switching diode, or even a Schottky diode. It doesn't have to be any particular type - as long as it's not very tiny, and is a modern part, it'll work. You can probably even use a LED.

In fact, you already got pretty good silicon diodes: the transistor's C-B diode. Just use that. The transistor is Q2, the eqivalent silicon diode D2 is shown to its right.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNiOKS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The turn-off time of the relay can be improved by allowing the flyback voltage to get higher than a single diode drop. You can use the reverse B-E "Zener" voltage, typically 5-6V, to that effect. The equivalent diodes are shown on the right.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe1nHn.png)</sup>

> The circuit diagram calls for a 1N4007 diode

In this application, that diode is a stand-in for anything between 1N4001 and 1N4007, and a lot of other silicon diodes.

Comment: It often goes missed, that the relay coil's current will never be higher than its forward ("on") current -- 1N4007s are frequently seen, but not because of ratings! Just because they're cheap and common as sand. A solution like this is indeed satisfactory -- good answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136978/discussion-between-tim-williams-and-kuba-hasnt-forgotten-monica).

Comment: Yes, I know 1N4007 is a good stand in for others. It just happens to be the one called for that I now have.